# Why does JProfiler snapshot file grow over time?

Tags: jprofiler

I setup a trigger that starts recording of CPU/thread/telemetry, sleep for a while, and write out a snapshot file, then stop recording of CPU/thread/telemetry with reset data.

It seems a snapshot file grows over time. Is this because of accumulated thread/telemetry data? If so, it will eventually eat up all the heap if it runs for very long like a year? Anyway to reset its data?

Thanks,
Takenori